# On the same straight line there cannot be constructed two similar and unequal segments of circles on the same side.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

So, according to this figure : http://aleph0.clarku.edu/~djoyce/java/elements/bookIII/propIII23.html
We cannot have similar segments of circles and unequal ones be built on the same side of the same straight line.

My question is : Can we build similar segments of circles but unequal ones ? (It seems to imply it)

The definition of similar segments of circles is : "Similar segments of circles are those which admit equal angles, or in which the angles equal one another."

Here is the link for it : http://aleph0.clarku.edu/~djoyce/java/elements/bookIII/defIII11.html

Thank you!

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Right now it looks like your post is contradicting itself, because you say we cannot have "similar segments of circles and unequal ones" and then ask if we can have "similar segments of circles but unequal ones", which is basically the same as far as I can tell.

Comment: Well, the proposition 23 says that we can't build similar segments of circles and unequal ones on the same sime of the same straight line. My question is, can we build similar segments of circles and unequal ones in some way, like for example one which isn't on the same side of the same straight line. Not sure how I can explain it ...

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. Well, [the very next proposition](http://aleph0.clarku.edu/~djoyce/java/elements/bookIII/propIII24.html) states that "Similar segments of circles on equal straight lines equal one another", and since a straight line is equal to itself, similar segments of circles on it cannot be unequal. So no.

Comment: Ok, but what about other cases where bases would be unequal ? Would this make it possible to be unequal and similar ?